# ¿Cómo puedo hacer una consulta en PostgreSQL sin discriminar minúsculas y mayúsculas?

Tags: postgresql

Resulta que quiero realizar una consulta en mi base de datos PostgreSQL para buscar un nombre específico. El problema es que ese nombre no sé si está en mayúscula o minúscula, por lo que debo ir probando todas las combinaciones:

```
SELECT * FROM personas WHERE nombre = 'Juan'
SELECT * FROM personas WHERE nombre = 'juan'
SELECT * FROM personas WHERE nombre = 'JUAN'
```

Como veis es algo tedioso y no me funciona algo como el MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM personas WHERE nombre LIKE '%Juan%'
```

¿Existe alguna forma de realizar la consulta consiguiendo los resultados sin que importe si están en mayúscula o minúscula?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mirando en [PostgreSQL: How to make “case-insensitive” query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7005302/1983854) veo que hay varias opciones:

- Usando [**`ILIKE`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-matching.html):

  ```
  SELECT * FROM personas WHERE nombre ILIKE 'juan'
  ```
- Usando [**`LOWER()`**](http://developer.postgresql.org/pgdocs/postgres/functions-string.html) para convertirlo todo a minúsculas (opcionalmente, lo mismo con mayúsculas):

  ```
  SELECT * FROM personas WHERE LOWER(nombre) = 'juan'
  ```

  que es lo mismo que

  ```
  SELECT * FROM personas WHERE LOWER(nombre) = LOWER('Juan')
  ```
- Usando expresiones regulares de POSIX con **`~*`**:

  ```
  SELECT * FROM personas WHERE nombre ~* 'Juan'
  ```